# What is the use of threading in Python despite of the limitations imposed by GIL?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get my head around this question. I did some research and found out that the multithreading a task would be lot slower than sequential task. The same is mentioned by respected David Beazley in some of his concurrency tasks. To achieve similar (kind of) behavior I can spawn a new process using multiprocessing module but spawning a process takes more time than spawning a thread. So, I'm wondering what would be the use cases where can I use threading module other than I/O bound tasks. Please help me understand this.

Comment: "but spawning a process takes more time than spawning a task" Is this so? Source, please.

Comment: courotine side libraries like gevent or twsited is some kind of solution better in in performance than python's Threading lib (for me, at least)

Comment: @LutzHorn: edited: spawning a process takes more time than spawning a thread.

Comment: @HumbleLearner You already wrote that in your question. I asked for a source for this claim. Repeating the claim is not an answer.

Comment: @Anonymous: I know there are other solutions exist but that does not answer my question. Thanks for comment though.

Comment: considering this question, maybe you can find somethinig useful in this David Beazley talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4

Comment: @LutzHorn - Threads are light-weight compared to process. Marshalling, Adress space, handles etc. are huge expenses when you try to spawn a new processe.

Comment: @HumbleLearner Have you actually confirmed that using `multiprocessing` has a noticeable detrimental effect on performance in your use-case? There are cases where it definitely will (if you need to share a lot of state between processes), but if you're not passing a lot of data from parent to child (or vice versa) the extra overhead of forking/spawning processes will likely be dwarfed by the time saved by doing your computations in parallel.

Comment: @LutzHorn Spawning (and even forking) a process is definitely slower than creating a thread. You can test it with `timeit`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dano/dafc1067b4ae77afb08b) for an example. That said, the extra cost of spawning/forking a process, or even ten, will likely be dominated by the computations going on inside the processes. So, it's really only a concern if you're doing very little work inside each, or passing a lot of state - the process spawn time increases as the amount of state being passed to each increases, which can make the performance difference much larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual limitation is a CPython limitation, not a language one. Given that, threading can be used to run concurrent tasks, as long as (in CPython) only one task has python code.

Besides IO, an example would be c extensions that perform lengthy computations and release the GIL (in CPython's case).

Comment: So, If I'm doing lengthy computation in python code itself then threading is probably not useful in that case. Currently, I have a task that does a lengthy computations. I'm not allowed to write any C extensions for this. So, I don't know what's the best thing I can do. May be, use numpy along with threads to make it bit faster. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @HumbleLearner Correct. You can investigate cython (http://cython.org/). Also check http://wiki.scipy.org/ParallelProgramming. Numpy at certain points can be used in a multithreading context.